# Please review a solution involving maximizing of volume

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A coffee filter is to be made from a circle of radius $1$ with a sector with the central angle $x$ cut from it such that $V$, the volume of the coffee held in the filter is maximized. Find the volume $V$.

**I assumed that the angle $x$ is in radians**.

I assumed the radius of the cone formed as $r$.

---

The lateral surface area of cone will be $$L=\pi rl=\pi r$$
Here $l=1$ as it will be equal to the radius of the circle.

Area of sector$$L=\pi(1)^2\frac{x}{2\pi}=\frac{x}{2}$$
Since both areas have to be equal $\implies$ $$\pi r=\frac{x}{2}$$ or $$r=\frac{x}{2\pi}$$
Now the volume of the cone is $$\frac13\cdot\pi \frac{x^2}{4{\pi}^2}\cdot h$$ or $$\frac{x^2h}{12\pi}$$
Since $l=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$ $\implies$ $l^2-r^2=h^2$ or we can say that $h=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4{\pi}^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{4{\pi}^2-x^2}{4{\pi}^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{4{\pi}^2-x^2}}{2\pi}$

Therefore volume is $$\frac{x^2\sqrt{4{\pi}^2-x^2}}{24\pi}$$ Differentiating it with respect to $x$ gives $$-\dfrac{3x^3-8{\pi}^2x}{24{\pi}\sqrt{4{\pi}^2-x^2}}$$ Now equating it with $0$ gives $$x=\dfrac{2^\frac{3}{2}{\pi}}{\sqrt{3}}$$ The other two values were discarded as they were not positive. Now putting this $x$ in the volume formula gives $$\frac{2{\pi}^2}{9\sqrt{3}}$$ So this must be the maximum volume. But I am not sure. Can anyone review$?$

Comment: Looks good to me. Good job! I would perform an additional check that the value of $x$ is indeed a maximum.

Comment: This seems correct to me.